# rearrange the appended text input when remove button clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a add button. when i click on it it get append new input text with placeholder option A,B,C,D,E with a remove button each. when i click on remove button of c then it shows the order A,B,D,E. but i need to get arrange as A,BD replace with C,E replace with C .
[image: first image]
[image: second image]
[image: third image]

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-2 input-group" id="optionList">
                                                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="myopt" placeholder="Option A" name="myopt[]" required><br>
                                                                            &nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="button" class="btn btn-icon rounded-circle btn-success glow mr-1 mb-1 add_field_button"><i class="bx bx-list-plus"></i></button>
                                                                        </div>
```

```
var x = 1; //initlal text box count
            var nex = 'A'.charCodeAt(0);
            $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
                e.preventDefault();
                if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
                    var curr = String.fromCharCode(nex+x++);
                    $(wrapper).append('<div class="input-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="myopt" placeholder="Option '+curr+'" name="myopt[]" required><button type="button" class="btn btn-icon rounded-circle btn-light-danger mr-1 mb-1 remove_field"><i class="bx bx-minus"></i></button><br></div>'); //add input box
                }
            });
```

Comment: plz, can u help me to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add code like below on remove button click.

You delegate type biding with `$(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_field', function(e) {` so it will work for dynamically added `button`.

On click remove parent div.

Reset `x` & `nex` values.

Loop over all `input` except `first` inside `wrapper` and reset `placeholder` value.

```
$(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_field', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().remove();
    x = 1;
    nex = 'B'.charCodeAt(0);

    $(wrapper).find('input[type=text]:not(:first)').each(function(i, item) {
        x++; //text box increment
        var curr = String.fromCharCode(nex++);
        $(this).attr('placeholder', 'Option ' + curr);
    })
});
```

Test it here.

```js
var max_fields = 5; //maximum input boxes allowed
var wrapper = $("#optionList"); //Fields wrapper
var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

var x = 1; //initlal text box count
var nex = 'B'.charCodeAt(0);

$('.add-btn').click(function(e) { //on add input button click
  e.preventDefault();
  if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
    x++; //text box increment
    var curr = String.fromCharCode(nex++);
    $(wrapper).append('<div class="input-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="myopt" placeholder="Option ' + curr + '" name="myopt[]" required><button type="button" class="btn btn-icon rounded-circle btn-light-danger mr-1 mb-1 remove_field"><i class="bx bx-minus"></i>Remove</button><br></div>'); //add input box
  }
});

$(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_field', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().remove();
  x = 1;
  nex = 'B'.charCodeAt(0);
  $(wrapper).find('input[type=text]:not(:first)').each(function(i, item) {
    x++; //text box increment
    var curr = String.fromCharCode(nex++);
    $(this).attr('placeholder', 'Option ' + curr);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='button' class='add-btn' value='add'>

<div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-2 input-group" id="optionList">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="myopt" placeholder="Option A" name="myopt[]" required><br> &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-icon rounded-circle btn-success glow mr-1 mb-1 add_field_button"><i class="bx bx-list-plus"></i></button>
</div>
```

Comment: the removal of dynamic text is working. and here i need if i delete c then replace d become c and  e become d

Comment: no sir, if i click the remove of c it removing the last e,d,c,b

Comment: Have you tested with Run code snippet. When I remove `C` it will remove `C`. Replace `placeholder` of `D` with `C`. Replace `placeholder` of `E` with `D`. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: sir, i updated my question content by adding current output image in third

Comment: the deletion works as i thought, but te issue now is i need only A,B,C,D,E . here i get after E. 
how can i rotate with A,B,C,D,E

Comment: I think you might have not reset value of ` x = 1;` or `nex = 'B'.charCodeAt(0);`.